# Can I use the Facebook API to fetch images off my profile?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a blog. I want to add a bit of Javascript on my blog to fetch images from my Facebook profile and display them on the blog.

I have zero experience with the Facebook API, so at this point I'm just wondering whether this is possible. **Can I run some Javascript on my blog to fetch images from my Facebook profile?** Or does the Facebook API disallow such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only ever worked with Facebook API in PHP. However I know there is a JavaScript SDK available, which you can find information about here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

You'll probably have to do the following:

1) Setup a Facebook application
2) Make it request permission to your photo galleries and offline access (for non-expiring token)
3) Retrieve the access token.
4) Use the call functions to get what content you want using the access_token to prove who you are.

Unfortunately I can't help anymore than that.